# Apache server Method Not Allowed when requesting from http://localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, vuejs2, virtualhost

I'm having problem understanding if my code is wrongly formatted or i have something wrongly configured on apache server. I'm developing application in VueJs2 which is working on `http://localhost:8080` (via npm run dev) and I'm making request on my Apache2 server (MAMP) which has virtual host on myapp.test. I have enabled all Access-Control options which I know, but when ever I set header in my get request (in js code), developer tools show that this request method is OPTIONS and I'm not authorized. If I delete headers in my JS code, request response is 200 OK (method GET).

this is my js code from vuejs2

```
this.$http.get(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/public/User/user/` + payload.id_user, {
    // if i remove this headers, request works OK
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'JwtToken': token
    }
})
```

And this is my apache virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName spotscouting.test
    ServerAlias *.spotscouting.test
    ServerAdmin info@spotscouting.test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/davorpecnik/workspace/spot-scouting-adminpage"
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog "/Users/davorpecnik/workspace/spot-scouting-adminpage/rest/application/logs/spotscouting.test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/davorpecnik/workspace/spot-scouting-adminpage/rest/application/logs/spotscouting.test-access_log" common
    <Directory   "/Users/davorpecnik/workspace/spot-scouting-adminpage">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory> 
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" 
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
</VirtualHost>
```

Network in developer tools
[image]

Can you please tell me what is wrong?
If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you

Comment: The formatting of your code has nothing to do with this issue, for what is worth.

Comment: Browsers do a "preflight" check using an OPTIONS request. Add OPTIONS to your list of allowed methods.

Comment: i have added options to my methods and I still have same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTIONS is a pre-flight request sent when making the http calls.

As explained in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)

> In CORS, a preflight request with the OPTIONS method is sent, so that the server can respond whether it is acceptable to send the request with these parameters. The Access-Control-Request-Method header notifies the server as part of a preflight request that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a POST request method. The Access-Control-Request-Headers header notifies the server that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a X-PINGOTHER and Content-Type custom headers.  The server now has an opportunity to determine whether it wishes to accept a request under these circumstances.

In your Apache Virtual Host, add the OPTIONS in

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

You would also need to set the appropriate header in order to make a successful request. For JWT Token, you can send it through Authorization header.

```
this.$http.get(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/public/User/user/` + payload.id_user, {
    // if i remove this headers, request works OK
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
})
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. I have updated my virtual host and network image in my question

Comment: I think it's the jwtToken that you are sending in the header. Try sending the authorization token as 'Authorization'.  headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
    }

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are encountering a CORS issue. A pre-flight request is made (the OPTIONS one) because you are setting the `'Content-Type'` header to `'application/json'`. You may want to try adding 'OPTIONS' to the allow-headers

Content-Type is usually fine but only for the following values:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
text/plain
```

[See here for explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: doesn't Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers allow this in my virtaulhost configuration?

Comment: The request made with the OPTIONS http method is the one that is failing first I believe. Which would make a subsequent request also fail

Comment: I still have the same problem. I have updated my virtual host and network image in my question

Comment: Sometimes CORS issues aren't immediately obvious. I recently dealt with the same issue and my problem eventually was found to stem from a configuration in IIS. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Apache server but I suggest to look at apache server related CORS issues